# How to write the assert format for msg.value > 0.01 ether in truffle test

Tags: testing, solidity, assert, smartcontracts, truffle

In card.sol contract, I have a function 'add' which allows a user to create a poker card with any number. To use this 'add' function, it requires at least 0.01 eth.

I have written the following truffle test scripts to ensure that at least 0.01 eth is used to create a card in the smart contract above.

```
var Web3 = require('web3');

const card = artifacts.require("card");

contract('card Test', async accounts => {

    it("ensure > 0.01 eth is needed to create a card", async () => {
        const instance = await Card.deployed();
        const cardInstance = instance;
        await cardInstance.add(5, 10, {from: accounts[0], value: Web3.utils.toWei('0.02')});
        assert.isAbove(____________, 0.01, "> 0.01 eth is needed to create the card");
      });
```

What is the correct code for ____________?

For the usual solidity test scripts, it will be 'msg.value'. What is the equivalence of 'msg.value' for the _________ above?

Comment: What do you mean by "creating card". You mean calling `cardInstance.add` cost you 0.01

Comment: @Yilmaz  Thank you for replying.  I have added a (first) paragraph in the question above to explain the context. Is it clearer now?     Yes, the user needs to spend at least 0.01 eth to use the cardInstance.add function.

Comment: in your contract, for `add` function, do you have `require` statement for msg.value>0.01

Comment: @Yilmaz  Yes, I have the following line in my card.sol.

`require(msg.value > 0.01 ether, "at least 0.01 ETH is needed to create a new card.");`

Comment: so you want to check if this `require` statement is working, right?

Comment: @Yilmaz  Yes I want to check if this require statement is working. 
At the moment I have this:  
`   it("ensure > 0.01 eth is needed to create a card", async () => {  

        const amount = Web3.utils.toWei('0.02');  
        const instance = await Card.deployed();  
        const cardInstance = instance;  
        await cardInstance.add(5, 10, {from: accounts[0], value: amount});  
        assert.isAbove(parseInt(amount), parseInt(Web3.utils.toWei('0.01')), "> 0.01 eth is needed to create the card");  
      });`

I am unsure if this way is proper.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243566/discussion-between-futuristicoptimist-and-yilmaz).

Answer (score 0):

you have to send amount that less than 0.01 Assuming that created the instance correctly

```
try {
   // this will throw error and you will catch it catch statement
   await cardInstance.add(5, 10, {from: accounts[0], value:Web3.utils.toWei('0.00001')})
     // if this line executed, your test will fail.
      assert(false);
    } catch (e) {
      // to test this part of your code executed
      console.log("errror is caught")
      // this will confirm that we get an error object
      assert(e);
    }
```

If you send less than minimum requirement, if we are successfully catching the error in catch statement, test case will pass. If there was an error with `require` statement  `assert(false)` would run and test case would fail

Comment: May I know what assert(false) do?

Comment: @futuristicoptimist you are not supposed the get error. we are successfully catching the error in catch statement.

Comment: it("ensure > 0.01 eth is needed to create a card", async () => {  
    //const amount = Web3.utils.toWei('0.01');  
    const instance = await card.deployed();  
    const cardInstance = instance;

    try {
        await cardInstance.add(5, 10, {from: accounts[0], value: Web3.utils.toWei('0.0001')})
            assert(false);
        } catch (e) {
            assert(e);
        }
    
  });



I tried your code above but no error is being caught. Is my syntax incorrect?

Comment: @futuristicoptimist I rxplained in code. when you send less money,  `await cardInstance.add` will throw an error and  you will catch it in catch statement. to check you are catching,  `console.log("errror is caught")` before `assert(e);`

Comment: Ok I got you. If I test the above code with something that will not fail the `require(>0.01 eth)` statement, e.g.,  `value:Web3.utils.toWei('0.1')`,   does it have any meaning?

Comment: @futuristicoptimist try it. this time catch statement will not fired. Instead `assert(false)` should run and your test should fail

Comment: I did try it.................it did not fail.

Comment: make sure, you passed more value than minimum requirement. send higher amount to cover the gas cost as well

Comment: Yes I tried it with ('1') too.  It passed the test case. Is it because there is no error to be caught?

Comment: @futuristicoptimist that is the whole point of `assert(false);`. think about it. your `add` function will execute and then `assert(false);` should be executed and it should throw error. when you pass a higher value, does `console.log` in catch statement fires?

Comment: I am writing testing script for solidity files, so console.log() is not available.

Comment: What do u mean. Arent you writing turffle test. in `test.js` extension file